# Get background image of element from Event object : Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to get background image URL from Event object, Trying following:

**.ts file:**

```
  openZoomer(event) {
    if (event.target.className === 'ngx-gallery-image ngx-gallery-active') {
      this.current_image = event.target.style.background.url;
      this.isZooming = true;
    }
  }
```

**.html file:**

```
(click)="openZoomer($event)"
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Use,

```
target.style.backgroundImage
```

instead of

```
event.target.style.background.url
```

it will give something like this

```
"url("someurl")"
```

then use replace function to extract the urlpart

```
event.target.style.backgroundImage.replace("url\(","").replace("\)","").replace("\"","").replace("\"","");
```

then you will get 
**someurl**